# Spring integration Implement retry for a failed message with exponential backoff in Serviceactivator

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am working on a task that **requires sending requests** to **external soap service client** after reading messages in a request message-channel (Queuechannel) with original source being `ibm mq`.
Message channels gets data from `ibm mq` using message driven adapter.
Message channel gets polled by a `poller` (incorporating throttling required by soap service vendor by `maxmessagesperchannel`) that sends those messages to my service activator.
`Serviceactivator`(soap client) in turn connects to a soap service and gets response back after making some logic based on header value in Message.
When I get certain error code I need to do reprocessing of this particular message.
I have requirement from this external soap service vendor that we retry or resend this message in exponential manner .e.g 1s, 1minute, 1 hour if sequential failures happen in retry after 1s, 1m and 1 hour.
If after 1 hour retry it fails we put it to manual check queue which is not of concern at present.
To retry the requests we implemented `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice` in spring integration and throw a custom `reprocessingexception` (runtimex) which is triggering `circuitbreaker` and are dynamically changing `circuitbreakers` `halfOpenAfter` value but it doesn't solve our purpose.
How we make sure that our failed request is only one thats retried after circuit opens.
One more problem is `poller` continuously runs when `circuitbreaker` is open causing other messages also to fail.
All messages failed go to a default `errorChannel` for additional information.?
Ritesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [retry advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#retry-advice) with an `ExponentialBackOffPolicy` instead of the circuit breaker.

Comment: Hi Gary still I need help in a following scenario if you can suggest please, 1) We configured retry advice for the use case when we get certain error back from external service for 10 sec, 50 sec, and so on upto hour. If we get error like timeout we open a circuitbreaker using circuitbreaker advice for 3 sec halfOpenAfter but there can be downtimes of 1 h frm our external soap service. We use task executor 20 pool. 20/sec polled using poller frm a channel(source is ibm mq). In big downtime many messages can go into retry can exhaust the executors.Can we configure to not exhaust the executors?

Comment: Can we configure in case of big downtime to stop poller using Jmx configuration? Regards,Ritesh

Comment: You can use a caller-runs or caller blocks rejection policy on the executor. Yes, you can stop the poller either via a direct reference or by sending a message to a control bus.